# jQuery variable scope? says undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
  (function ($) {

    var contact, name, email, entry;
    emails = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      contact = contacts[i];
      emails[i]['name'] = contact.fullName();
      emails[i]['email'] = contact.selectedEmail();
    }

    $.post("/cloudsponge-post",emails,function(data) {

    });
  }(jQuery));
}
```

I get the following error when I try and run it:

```
WARN: Attempt to invoke callback [afterSubmitContacts] failed: TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what the problem is- I'm quite new to JS and finding it a bit tricky. What's the reason it's broken, and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Your emails in an object, not a array, so emails[i] is undefined. Also you forgot the var before it.

Comment: I can remember being forced to do = { } before setting objects properties so i assumed it was the same for arrays.

Comment: Mind if I ask why use an IIFE directly inside a function? The function creates its own scope. Does it have to do with Drupal using the `$` variable?

Comment: Probably to use $ without conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you could write this code, but personally I would do this:

```
function postToDrupal( contacts, source, owner ) {
    // TODO: source and owner are unused

    var emails = jQuery.map( contacts, function( contact ) {
        return {
            name: contact.fullName(),
            email: contact.selectedEmail()
        }
    });

    jQuery.post( '/cloudsponge-post', emails, function( data ) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That object `emails[i]` is not yet defined. try this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  contact = contacts[i];
  emails[i] = {}; //Instantiate it here
  emails[i]['name'] = contact.fullName();
  emails[i]['email'] = contact.selectedEmail();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an object to store a list. I suggest changing `emails` declaration to an array .

Comment: @MarlonBernardes: He has string keys. It needs to be an object. Why should he use an array?

Comment: @Mark Actually I'm referring to the "outer" data structure. He needs an array of objects. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want an array instead of an object. So you should change `emails = {}` to `emails = []`.

If you do as @PSL suggested you will end with an object like this (which is not an array):

```
{
  0: {
    name: 'john'
    email: 'john@john.com'
  },
  1: {
    name: 'lennon'
    email: 'lennon@lennon.com'
  }
}
```

One possible solution:

```
var contact, name, email, entry,
  emails = [];

for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  contact = contacts[i];
  emails.push({name: contact.fullName(), email: contact.selectedEmail()});
}
```

You'll end up with this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'john'
    email: 'john@john.com'
  }
  ,{
    name: 'lennon'
    email: 'lennon@lennon.com'
  }
]
```

Comment: Your forgot the semi-colon, poor quality copy ;-)

Comment: I didn't copy your post - and the semicolon is not needed by the way :)

Comment: @PSL that's why I always do it :)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Anyone? I'd be really grateful to know.